# git like solution for images other none-code files

Tags: git, version-control

I am using git for quite a while know. It is really great to manage source code files and keep track of different version. However, I have a lot of files that belong to my projects but not to the source code, e.g.

- PDF document like the contract with my customers
- Photoshop PSD files
- Excel files with project schedule, issues, etc.
- Invoices
- MS Visio files for different diagrams
- ...

Of course I could add these files to the git repo of my project but I would prefer to keep these files separated from the source code file. First reason is, that a lot of these files should not be accessible to the different developers that work on the code. This could still be solved by using two different repos of course. Second reason is, that git is designer to work best with text files. Of course it would work with images, pdf, psd, etc. but it would not be an ideal solution.

Most of these files will change not very often, but when they change, they will be completely replaced. For example most of the invoices are generated once and never changed. If an invoice needs to be changed, it is replaced by a new file.

Thus I am looking for a solution that is designed to handle large binary files and to keep track of complete file changes (not small changes within a file). I think **Backup** would be a much better description than **Version Control** for this scenario.

I thought about using **rsync** or similar tools. However this does not offer any version control at all: If File-A is replaced be a new version with the same name, rsync will simply override the file with its new version, without any possibility to go back to the previous version.

**Appel Time Machine** or **Genie Timeline** would be tools, that come very close to what I am looking for. However these tools are designed to keep versioned backups on some local storage and not to use different remotes like git.

**So: Is there any good solution out there, that is build to handle (more or less) static files in a git-like way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into https://git-lfs.github.com/